# Cannot get FB.api response with js class

Tags: javascript, facebook

this is my code:

```
function User() {
    var self = this;

    FB.api(someurl, function (response) {

        self.id = response.id;

    });
}
```

I can't get the id going like this:

```
var user = new User();
console.log(user.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

FB.api is an asynchronous function with a callback. At the time you read `user.id` the callback function has not been called yet.

Maybe you should move the async initialization out of the constructor, adding an explicit "init" function:

```
function User() {
    var self = this;

    this.init = function(onCompletion) {
        FB.api(someurl, function (response) {
            self.id = response.id;
            if (onCompletion) onCompletion();
        });
    }
}

var user = new User();
user.init(function(){
    console.log(user.id);
});
```

Comment: Ok then, how would I do that? I just want to store response.id and response.email in order to use them several time without calling FB.login.

Comment: It's fine to store them for later use; you just have to be sure to not access those cached values before they are loaded. If you need them as soon as possible, use the init callback.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
FB.api(someurl, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

and post here response value.

Comment: everything's fine with response. {name:"some name", email: "some@address.com", id:123456789}

Comment: so try: 

function User() {
    var self = this;

      self.id = 123456;


}

var user = new User();
console.log(user.id);

what do you get?

Comment: 123456. the problem is getting the value within FB.api

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a pattern where you initialize your object, then using a callback in your asynchronous request. Something like this:

```
function User() {
    var self = this;
    self.init = function(cb) { 
        FB.api(someurl, function (response) {

            self.id = response.id;
            if (cb) { 
               cb();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then

```
var user = new User();
user.init(function() { console.log(user.id); });
```